# FirebaseAuth.signInWithEmailAndPassword

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-authentication

I'm having an issue with

```
FirebaseAuth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
```

I'm getting the error message

> non-static method 'signInWithEmailAndPassword(java.lang.string, java.lang.string)' cannot be referenced from a static context.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {


        private Button loginButton;
        private EditText username;
        private EditText passwordLogin;
        private TextView signUpText;
        private ProgressDialog progressDialog;
        private FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth;


        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

            firebaseAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();

            if(firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser() != null){
                finish();
                startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(), dashBoard.class));
            }

            progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(this);
            username = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.username);
            passwordLogin = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.passwordLogin);
            loginButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.loginButton);
            signUpText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.signUpText);


            loginButton.setOnClickListener(this);
            signUpText.setOnClickListener(this);



        }

        private void userLogin(){

            String email = username.getText().toString().trim();
            String password = passwordLogin.getText().toString().trim();

            if (TextUtils.isEmpty(email)){
                //username is empty
                Toast.makeText(this, "Please enter username", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                return;
            }

            if (TextUtils.isEmpty(password)){
                //password is empty
                Toast.makeText(this, "Please enter your password", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }

            progressDialog.setMessage("Logging in user");
            progressDialog.show();

            FirebaseAuth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
                    .addOnCompleteListener(this, new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                            progressDialog.dismiss();
                             if(task.isSuccessful()){
                                 finish();
                                 Intent intent= new Intent(MainActivity.this,dashBoard.class);
                                 startActivity(intent);                         }
                        }
                    });
        }


    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {

        if ( view == loginButton){
            userLogin();
        }

        if(view == signUpText) {
            startActivity(new Intent(this, userRegistration.class));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Typo? `firebaseAuth.signInWithEmailAndPassword`... Small `f` in firebase

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to access a member function(non static) from a static context that is why it is giving to that error. For using that method, you first have to create an instance of `FirebaseAuth` and then call the `signInWithEmailAndPassword` method from that object.

```
FirebaseAuth mFirebaseAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance(); 
mFirebaseAuth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
    .addOnCompleteListener(this, new OnCompleteListener() {

        @Override
        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task task) {
            //your callback method will go here
        }
    });
```

Comment: You don't receive callback where you specified. You need to add OnCompleteListener / OnResultListener. See my answer.

Comment: @SumitJha I was focussing more on the error that was there, not on the firebase auth method. He got that right in the question itself.

Answer (score 0):

you should access that method using the Object "firebaseAuth" that you have already created. And also it looks from error that signInWithEmailAndPassword() is anon-static method, so it can not be accessed directly using class name. Check the code below and replace it.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {


        private Button loginButton;
        private EditText username;
        private EditText passwordLogin;
        private TextView signUpText;
        private ProgressDialog progressDialog;
        private FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth;


        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

            firebaseAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();

            if(firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser() != null){
                finish();
                startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(), dashBoard.class));
            }

            progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(this);
            username = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.username);
            passwordLogin = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.passwordLogin);
            loginButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.loginButton);
            signUpText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.signUpText);


            loginButton.setOnClickListener(this);
            signUpText.setOnClickListener(this);



        }

        private void userLogin(){

            String email = username.getText().toString().trim();
            String password = passwordLogin.getText().toString().trim();

            if (TextUtils.isEmpty(email)){
                //username is empty
                Toast.makeText(this, "Please enter username", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                return;
            }

            if (TextUtils.isEmpty(password)){
                //password is empty
                Toast.makeText(this, "Please enter your password", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }

            progressDialog.setMessage("Logging in user");
            progressDialog.show();

            firebaseAuth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
                    .addOnCompleteListener(this, new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                            progressDialog.dismiss();
                             if(task.isSuccessful()){
                                 finish();
                                 Intent intent= new Intent(MainActivity.this,dashBoard.class);
                                 startActivity(intent);                         }
                        }
                    });
        }


        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

            if ( view == loginButton){
                userLogin();
            }

            if(view == signUpText) {
                startActivity(new Intent(this, userRegistration.class));
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to access non-static (member) function from static context. Hence the error.

```
    private final FirebaseAuth mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();

   mAuth.signInWithEmailAndPassword("email_here", "password_here").addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<AuthResult>() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(AuthResult authResult) {
            // If authentication is successful, you receive callback here.
            // You can get uId (userId) of the logged in user as..
            String userId = authResult.getUser().getUid();

        }
    });
```